# As3: Draw overlapping rectangles to a sprite and apply alpha

Tags: actionscript-3, graphics, sprite, draw

I need to draw **independet** rectangles to a sprite. But the **overlapping areas** will get visible if I apply **alpha** to my sprite (the sprite will be fade in and out):

```
        var spBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
        this.addChild(spBox);

        spBox.graphics.beginFill(0x123456)
        spBox.graphics.drawRect(100, 100, 50, 50);
        spBox.graphics.endFill();

        spBox.graphics.beginFill(0x123456)
        spBox.graphics.drawRect(125, 125, 50, 50);
        spBox.graphics.endFill();
```

[image: Sprite rectangles with alpha applied]

Is there a way to **compine/flatten/merge** the rectangles of my sprite? I want a seamless aplha appearence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect that the graphics object does not support this kind of functionality for parts of its data.

If both boxes are individual `DisplayObjects`, you can set the `.blendMode` of the `DisplayObjectContainer` to `BlendMode.LAYER,` which gives the desired result. Here's some example code that refactors the drawing of a rectangle into a `Box` class:

```
var spBox:Sprite = new Sprite();
this.addChild(spBox);


var a:Box = new Box(50, 50, 0x123456);
a.x = a.y = 100;
spBox.addChild(a);  

var b:Box = new Box(50, 50, 0x123456);
b.x = b.y = 125;
spBox.addChild(b);    

spBox.alpha = .5;
spBox.blendMode = BlendMode.LAYER;
```

The relevant parts of the `Box` class look like this:

```
public class Box extends Shape
{
    public function Box(width:Number = 100, height:Number = 100, color:uint = 0)
    {
        graphics.beginFill(color)
        graphics.drawRect(0, 0,  width, height);
        graphics.endFill();
    }
}
```